# How to create nested map from array of maps in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

So, as a result of a database call, I get a vector of maps, which let's say look like this:

```
[{:make "vw",  :model "vanagon", :color "blue",   :year 1983}
 {:make "vw",  :model "vanagon", :color "red",    :year 1987}
 {:make "vw",  :model "eurovan", :color "blue",   :year 1995}
 {:make "vw",  :model "eurovan", :color "green",  :year 1997}
 {:make "geo", :model "metro",   :color "blue",   :year 1985}
 {:make "geo", :model "metro",   :color "yellow", :year 1994}]
```

How can I get that into a nested map using two of the fields, e.g. like this:

```
{"vw"  {"vanagon" [{:color "blue", :year 1983}, {:color "red", :year 1987}]
        "eurovan" [{:color "blue", :year 1995}, {:color "green", :year 1997}]}
 "geo" {"metro" [{:color "blue", :year 1985}, {:color "yellow", :year 1994}]}}
```

I have been messing around with `group-by` and other coll functions for a couple hours, and I can't wrap my head around it and figure out a reasonable way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(reduce (fn [aggr {:keys [make model] :as row}]
          (update-in aggr
                     [make model]
                     (fnil conj [])
                     (dissoc row :make :model)))
        {} data)
```

The anonymous function does a [destructuring bind](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring). [`update-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) rewrites bound structure. The basic idea is to use `conj` to add in the other elements of the row.  `fnil` is there to specify that we want vectors (when nil is found use the empty vector as the 1st argument to `conj`).  Results are combined in a map by `reduce`.

Comment: Awesome! Still need to completely grok what's going on there, but this does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: As a follow-up, though, what if I don't necessarily know all of the items in the maps that aren't use to construct the hierarchy? E.g. what if the original maps may have additional entries, and I want them in the leaf maps at the end, without knowing ahead of time what they are?

Comment: Edited my answer to preserve any entry not used for the path.